# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed

Tags: google-chrome, web, websocket, browser

I have used websocket in the past but now even if i am not using it
my browser still shows me this error whenever i open any web page on any host
facebook, youtube, even localhost with only dummy website shows this error

```
reload.js:22 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5500//ws' failed:
```

Comment: Are errors printed to the DevTools console?

Comment: Yes It is in the console

Comment: Uninstall unused extensions.
If that doesn't help, try disabling extensions one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but you probably are using **"Live Server Web Extension"** so try to disable it